# When connecting to a server with JavaMail, what is the supported version of SSL?

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail

I have an application that uses JavaMail to connect to a POP3 server via SSL and I'm getting questions from our security auditor about what level of SSL it supports (version, ciphers, etc).  Does anyone know?  Is there a way to exclude certain versions or ciphers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as what Java supports. See the JSSE Reference Guide for all those details.

Comment: Thanks.  This gave me the push in the right direction I needed.

Answer (score 0):

After reading EJP's answer and searching for the JSSE Reference Guide I found this.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

Which led me to the answer that it is SSL 3.0.

Then I found that you can do this to get the default cipher suite:

```
((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).getDefaultCipherSuites()
```

Which on my machine gives the following output:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

Comment: You can control the protocols and cipher suites used by setting the [mail.pop3.ssl.protocols and mail.pop3.ssl.ciphersuites properties](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).  Or mail.pop3s.* if you're using the "pop3s" protocol.

Comment: You misread it. It is SSLv3, TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, and if your Java is new enough TLSV1.2.